# Could not able to understand recursion in for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, recursion

I could not able to understand `recursion` in `for loop`.
I am trying to understand a program `string permutation`,
Look at the code below

```
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
} 

int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";  
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

This code I have seen in internet. This is working fine.
But for me, it is difficult to understand.

So, I wrote a small recursion function to understand the the above `complex code`.

My code goes like this

```
void dec(int x)
{
    int i;
    if(x <= 0)//if(x==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
    for(i = 0;i <= 5; i++)
    {
        dec(--x);
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    }
}
int main()
{
    dec(5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am seeing the output is going to `-ve`.
I am totally perplexed how recursion is working in for loop.

As of now I understood, it has to run `dec(--x)`, until it reaches base condition `if (x<=0)`.
Then it should return back and print x as `5 4 3 2 1 0`
Instead of that it goes into `-ve` .
And in between how `+ve` integers are coming? I am totally confused... Please help me.

`Output` as

```
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
2
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
3
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
2
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
4
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
2
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
3
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
2
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
0
-1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please help me understanding recursion function.
I read books and `Fibonacci series and factorial` and all them. But no where I found recursion in loop.
Please help me, where my understanding is going wrong...?

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is the right place to ask this. you will get a lot of negative points. check out http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The loop goes six times. Each time, it decrements `x`.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @clcto: I have used visual studio debugger... but still confused.. how contril is coming back to `dec()` how it is going to `printf` can't understand

Comment: You step through it and you don't see how control is moving through the program ?

Comment: Never use loops in recursive functions!

Comment: Pen and paper or more `printf`s is your best way to understand the logic of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

All the `x`s and `i`s are different from each other.

Let's say you are using a very slow computer and running your program.

At 10:00 you run the instruction `dec(5)` in `main`. This creates an `x` with value 5 and an unitialized `i`. Let's call them `x[10:00]` and `i[10:00]`.

Then you enter the loop and assign `0` to `i[10:00]`. And call `dec()` again, this time wit6h the value 4 (when `x[10:00]` changes is irrelevant; it may be before or after the call). This second call creates a new `x` with value 4 (`x[10:01]`) and a new uninitialized `i` (`i[10:01]`).

In the loop you assign `0` to `i[10:01]` (`i[10:00]` still has `0`) and call `dec()`. Another `x` and `i` will be created.

And so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion function has min( n!, 5!) complexity, because it contains a loop, and calls itself within this loop.

For example, if you enter it with x=5:

it is >=0, so it does not stop.

There is a loop called 5 times, and within each step it calls the same function with decreasing argument.

That means: on first loop step it starts calling itself with argument x=4:

b) which also will start a loop (5 times) beginning with x=3

c) which also will start a loop (5 times) beginning with x=2

d) which also will start a loop (5 times) beginning with x=1

e) the last loop will also start a loop (5 times) and start calling itself, but because all arguments are <=0, it will eventually terminate

f) then the outer loop (that started with x=2) goes to x=1 (and eventually terminates)

g) then the outer loop (that started with x=3) goes to x=2 (and does everything between c) and f)

h) then the outer loop (that started with x=4) goes to x=3 (and does everything between b) and g)

i) and eventually your function will print min (n!,5!) numbers (because the inner loop is limited to 5).

Answer (score -2):

If you remove the `for` loop in `dec()`:

```
void dec(int x)
{
    if(x <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        dec(--x);
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
}
```

You will get the following output:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

Note that the numbers printed are from `0` to `4` because it is only when `x == 0` does `dec()` `return`.  The order of printing in this form of recursion is LIFO (last in first out).

Comment: To the downvoter or person who tried to edit this answer: If you've downvoted/tried to edit this answer because you think the output should print the numbers from 4 to 0, you are incorrect.  Please run the program and you'll see.